# How to subclass numpy.`ma.core.masked_array`?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-2.7, subclass

I'm trying to write a subclass a `masked_array`. What I've got so far is this:

```
class gridded_array(ma.core.masked_array):
    def __init__(self, data, dimensions, mask=False, dtype=None,
                 copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=0, fill_value=None,
                 keep_mask=True, hard_mask=None, shrink=True):
        ma.core.masked_array.__init__(data, mask, dtype, copy, subok,
                                      ndmin, fill_value, keep_mask, hard_mask,
                                      shrink)
        self.dimensions = dimensions
```

However, when now I create a `gridded_array`, I don't get what I expect:

```
dims = OrderedDict()
dims['x'] = np.arange(4)
gridded_array(np.random.randn(4), dims)

masked_array(data = [-- -- -- --],
             mask = [ True  True  True  True],
             fill_value = 1e+20)
```

I would expect an unmasked array. I have the suspicion that the `dimensions` argument I'm passing gets passed on the the `masked_array.__init__` call, but since I'm quite new to OOP, I don't know how to resolve this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: I'm on Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A word of warning: if you're brand new to OOP, subclassing `ndarrays` and `MaskedArrays` is not the easiest way to get started, by far...*

Before anything else, you should go and check this [tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html). That should introduce you to the mechanisms involved in subclassing `ndarrays`.

`MaskedArrays`, like `ndarrays`, uses the `__new__` method for creating class instances, not the `__init__`. By the time you get to the `__init__` of your subclass, you already have a fully instanciated object, with the actual initialization delegated to the `__array_finalize__` method. In simpler terms: your `__init__` doesn't work as you would expect with standard Python object. (*actually, I wonder whether it's called at all... After `__array_finalize__`, if I recall correctly...*)

Now that you've been warned, you may want to consider whether you really need to go through the hassle of subclassing a `ndarray`:

- What are your objectives with your `gridded_array`?
- Should you support *all* methods of `ndarrays`, or only some? All dtypes?
- What should happen when you take a single element or a slice of your object?
- Will you be using `gridded_arrays` extensively as inputs of NumPy functions ?

If you have a doubt, then it might be easier to design `gridded_array` as a generic class that takes a `ndarray` (or a `MaskedArray`) as attribute (say, `gridded_array._array`), and add only the methods you would need to operate on your `self._array`.

### Suggestions

- If you only need to "tag" each item of your `gridded_array`, you may be interested in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).
- If you only have to deal with floats, `MaskedArray` might be a bit overkill: just use `nans` to represent invalid data, a lot of numpy functions have `nans` equivalent. At worst, you can always mask your `gridded_array` when needed: taking a view of a subclass of `ndarray` with `.view(np.ma.MaskedArray)` should return a masked version of your input...

Comment: I want to add dimension variables to the array object, e.g. latitude, longitude, altitude. All these should be arrays themselves. That way, the `gridded_array` itself has all information needed to understand what it actually represents. Later, I want to add some broadcasting, i.e. having objects such that (lat, lon, alt) \times (lat, lon) yields (lat, lon, alt), for an arbitrary order of the dimensions of the individual objects. `float64` and `float32` are the only dtypes I need. Objects will be commonly used as inputs to NumPy functions.

Comment: @andreas: So, `lat`, `lon`, `alt` are attributes that need to be carried over, right ? Then, you may want to try to use a basic `MaskedArray`, but add some special attributes to its hidden `_optinfo` dictionary. Of course, things can go wrong if you take only one element of the array: what should the `lat`, `lon`, `alt` be?

Comment: yes, `lat`, `lon`, `alt` are attributes that need to be carried over. They could be called differently. There could be more or less. Order matters: First dimensional variable corresponts to `dim0` of `gridded_array` object and so on. If I take only one element, it would ideally still be a `gridded_array` with the dimensional variables (all of length 1). `ma.asarray(garr)` should just be a `masked_array`.

Comment: In the `gridded_array` class, I want to implement broadcasting (as stated above; is this already possible with core NumPy?), downsampling to a coarser grid, interpolation to finer grid.

Comment: OK. When you take element `[1,1]`, what should you get? a `gridded_array` with `lat[1]`, `lon[1]` ?

Comment: Yes, downsampling should be doable with NumPy, or at least with SciPy and NumPy, so should interpolation (check for the basic `delaunay`). But if you intend to work with geographic data, check for a GIS library that uses Python to get you started.

Comment: Yes, when I take element `[1,1]` I should get a `gridded_array` with `lat[1]`, `lon[1]`.

Comment: We gonna get moved to chat... Before that, try to find an existing library to get you started, but *make a detailed list of your requirement*: what should be the result of what condition, etc... Think test-driven development.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `masked_array` uses `__new__` instead of `__init__`, so your `dimensions` argument is being misinterpreted.

To override [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), use:

```
class gridded_array(ma.core.masked_array):
    def __new__(cls, data, dimensions, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super(gridded_array, cls).__new__(cls, data, *args, **kwargs)
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        return self
```