# Subclassing numpy.ma.MaskedArray

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to subclass numpy's `MaskedArray` to add an attribute, but seem to fail getting the proper result out.

I started out by following [the example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array) for subclassing a `numpy.ndarray`, which works fine.

Then I tried subclassing a `numpy.ma.MaskedArray` instead, as follows:

```
import numpy as np

class MyMaskedArray(np.ma.MaskedArray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)
        super(MyMaskedArray, self).__array_finalize__(obj)

arr = np.arange(5)
obj = MyMaskedArray(arr, info='information')
print obj.info
print obj[1:].info
```

which results in

```
information
None
```

I had expected "information" twice.

Replacing the line `obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)` with `obj = np.ma.MaskedArray(input_array).view(cls)` or `obj = np.ma.MaskedArray.__new__(cls, input_array)` didn't solve that problem (I went this way, since I'd like to pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to `__new__` in future incarnations of the subclass.)

Note that I also had to add a call to the `MaskedArray.__array_finalize` in my subclass' `__array_finalize__`, in contrast to the example for an `ndarray` subclass; if I don't do that, the `_mask` attribute is not found.

Perhaps someone could enlighten me:

- how to get `obj[1:].info` to keep the original `obj.info`
- why the `ndarray` does not need a super-class call for `__array_finalize__`, but `MaskedArray` does (more of a bonus question).

I would like to subclass `MaskedArray` instead of writing a container class, since the latter would lose several conveniences that come with `MaskedArray`s.

(Note: this is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597827/how-to-subclass-numpy-ma-core-masked-array), since I already "solved" the `__init__` / `__new__` issue.)

Comment: you need to at least also define `__array_wrap__` since masked array defines that. That may already be most of it actually...

Comment: @seberg Why would I not be able to use the default `__array_wrap__` from `MaskedArray`? The `ndarray` subclassing example does nothing special there, just calling the parents `__array_wrap__` (so no real need to override it).

Comment: Because that is how MaskedArray is build. While the default `__array_wrap__` just calls `__array_finalize__`, the MA one does not. You can dislike that, you could probably even change it, but that does not change the fact that at this time you have to define it (as well as `__getitem__`).

Comment: I ended up with overriding `__getitem__`. `__array_wrap__` didn't seem to do anything; I'd assume because that's only useful for ufuncs, and not for slicing.

Comment: It's 4 years ago I wonder it still helps. I happen to know of one project [CDAT](https://github.com/UV-CDAT/uvcdat) that subclasses masked_array. I had a quick look into the code, too complicated for me, but might serve as a reference for someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your slice to work as you wish, you may want to overload `__getitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    out = np.ma.MaskedArray.__getitem__(self, item)
    out.info = self.info
    return out
```

Ditto for `__setitem__`.

If your `info` attribute is relatively simple, such as in your example, you may want to look at the `_optinfo` attribute of `MaskedArray`, which was designed for this purpose: it's just a dictionary storing some information that must be kept somehow. Here's an example:

```
class MyMaskedArray(np.ma.MaskedArray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj._optinfo['info'] = info
        return obj

    @property
    def info(self):
        return self._optinfo.get('info', None)
```

Note that here, `.info` is a read-only property, but it's straightforward to make it writable.

**About** `__array_finalize__`

I'm not sure I understand your question: `ndarray` is itself the superclass. `MaskedArray` is a subclass of `ndarray` and as such needs to define a `__array_finalize__` method that tells in particular how to set the mask (via the `_mask` argument). Check this [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) for more information on subclassing.

In your example, you use your own `__array_finalize__` to set your `.info` attribute. In that case, you do have to call the parent method `MaskedArray.__array_finalize__`, it's basic Python subclassing. Note that you don't have to explicitly define `__array_finalize__` if you go the `_optinfo` way...

**Note**

- The `__array_prepare__` and `__array_wrap__` methods are actually used to prepare an instance of a `ndarray` subclass before applying a function to it and to process the result of the function

Comment: The [subclassing ndarray example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array) does not override `__getitem__`, as it appears it can use `__array_finalize__` to deal with slices. Why can't `MaskedArray` not use this? As far as calling the parents method when overriding: I agree, it's what I'd do (and did), but again, the example given does not call the parents `__array_finalize__`; so my second question can also be phrased as: why not (call `__array_finalize__`)?